# KVM over IP solutions

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-switch

I am currently doing research into the KVM over IP market. As i am a college student, for more than half the year, I am away from home.

At home, I have a Ubuntu server  which I have hosting many services. I usually have no problem connecting over SSH, but for those few times where there is an issue, (usually something I screwed up), I must go for weeks without server access until I go home.

**Can anyone recommend a KVM over IP style solution for me?** I would live to have a real rackmounted KVM IP switch, but i dont have the $600 that would cost me (the poor college student)

Comment: Some solutions require that you have a Microsoft Domain Server to tie into.  When purchasing these products, if you don't have such a beast available, you may want to make sure that the product doesn't require one.

Comment: Hi!  Shopping recommendations are off-topic for SuperUser. Please see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#questions) for more info.

Comment: @techie007 Sorry, I originally posted this to serverfault, but someone else sent it over here, not I.

Comment: @Peaches491 - No big deal. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Lantronix SecureLinx Spider (My favorite!!)
- Avocent DSR1024 Single-port IP KVM (Has been replaced with "Avocent MergePoint Unity family, but I can't find a single-user device)
- Minicom PX 1 to 1 KVM over IP Server Access and Control with Virtual Media
- Raritan Dominion KX II-101
- Raritan eRIC G4
- AdderLink IPEPS

Comment: The Spider has two Ethernet ports?

Comment: @Peaches491 It has one Ethernet port and then a "cascade" port which is in essence a single port switch. This means that you don't need to Ethernet drops at the device location. For example, I'll place the Spider on a PC, the network cable from the wall goes into the Spider and then the PC's network cable goes into the Spider. Both Spider and PC have connectivity.

Comment: Ahh. Very clever Lantronix.